# Scrolled composite is getting cropped out but after refresh it expands to normal

Tags: java, swt

I have an editor opened on a component A and when I switch to another component B, the editor gets shrunk to a small box on the left corner of the editor screen. I can only see a part of the editor. Other parts are cropped out. This cropped part will remain as it is when I switch back to component A as well. It only happens when I switch to Component B. I’m new to SWT development and correct me if I’m wrong, I think why it shrinks is because of the scrolled form. If I double click on the screen, the editor goes back to normal screen size.

I tried:
I set both `expandHorizontal` and `expandVertical` to `true` and also `setMinSize(SWT.default, Swt.default)` but still didn’t work.

Comment: SWT.DEFAULT has a value of -1, the values to setMinSize need to be actual positive numbers from something like Composite.computeSize. There are far too many things that might be wrong to guess from a description. We need to see something closer to a [mre]

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the info..I was able to resolve this issue. Had to set the scrolled form parent’s layout to true (scrolledform.getParent().layout(true)) and now the editor opens in the right resolution.